# Setting the timeout when trying to connect to a remote server using HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httprequest

How to increase the timeout when connecting to a remote server uwing HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Please clarify. If you use System.Web.HttpRequest, it is typically instantiated by the ASP.NET runtime and you don't get to control the timeout on the server side. Or do you refer to System.Net.HttpWebRequest perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest_members.aspx), you should set Timeout to the desired value:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Timeout = 5000 // in ms, the default is 100,000
request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off there is `HttpWebRequest.Timeout`. [Details Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx)  (and in the answer that was posted while I was typing).. 
Second I would suggest using `System.Net.WebClient` which has a very simple to use interface. Setting a timeout on a WebClient is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile).