# http requests with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am looking to make http requests to web pages with powershell, is this possible and if so, how may I achieve this?

Can I make requests to https pages? I am able to make http requests with a bat file but not https, was hoping I could https page requests with powershell.

Comment: Are you requesting content from sites with certificates signed by well-known Certificate Authorities?  Browsers and most HTTP stacks balk at retrieving content from HTTPS sites with incorrect, expired, or self-signed (test) certificates.  You can usually set a policy to ignore the certificate issue or import the certificate in question, though.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the usual `WebRequest` and `HttpWebRequest` classes provided by the .NET framework.

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://example.com')
# do something with $request
```

It's no different from using the same classes and APIs from C#, except for the syntactic differences to PowerShell.

PowerShell v3 also brings `Invoke-WebRequest` and a few others.

Comment: And is it possible to make a request to https pages with the above?

Comment: yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https

Comment: Just in case anyone needs to send a POST request, since that was the next thing I needed:

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('mypageurl');
$request.Method = "POST";
$request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("name=john&number=5");
$request.ContentLength = $bytes.Length;

$requestStream = $request.GetRequestStream();
$requestStream.Write( $bytes, 0, $bytes.Length );
$requestStream.Close();

$request.GetResponse();

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

[WebClient.DownloadString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx)

or in PowerShell 3.0,

```
(Invoke-WebRequest http://stackoverflow.com).content
```

[Invoke-WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest)

Comment: Short and sweet, and works with a query string appended to the address too.

Comment: PowerShell 4 > `wget` is "sim-linked" to `Invoke-WebRequest`

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you are doing, you can also use [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), which is a simplified abstraction of `HttpWebRequest`

```
$client = new-object system.net.webclient
```

Look here for difference: [What difference is there between WebClient and HTTPWebRequest classes in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988286/what-difference-is-there-between-webclient-and-httpwebrequest-classes-in-net)

PS: With Powershell v3.0, you have `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlets which can be used for similar purposes

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, use Curl from http://curl.haxx.se .  You can set everything, including certificate handling, POSTs, etc.  Not subtle, but it works and handles all of the odder cases; e.g. you can set the --insecure flag to ignore certificate name issues, expiration, or test status.

Answer (score 2):

You can create HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and FILE requests using Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. This is pretty easy and gives many options to play around. 
Example: To make simple http/https requests to **google.com**

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://google.com"
```

More references can be found [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest)

Answer (score 0):

This code works with both ASCII & binary files over https in powershell:

```
# Add the necessary .NET assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http

# Create the HttpClient object
$client = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.Httpclient

# Get the web content.
$task = $client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715695/http-requests-with-powershell")

# Wait for the async call to finish
$task.wait();

# Write to file
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes('test.html',$task.result)
```

Tested on Powershell 5.1.17134.1, Win 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this PowerShell module: https://github.com/toolkitx/simple-request

Install by `Install-Module -Name SimpleRequest`
Then you can send requests like

```
$Data = @{
    "TokenUrl"     = 111
    "ClientSecret" = "222"
    "ClientId"     = "333"
    "AuthResource" = "444"
    "Username"     = "User1"
    "Password"     = "Password"
    "Id"           = 99
    "Price"        = 0.99
    "Value"        = "Content"
}

$Sample = '
POST https://httpbin.org/post?id={{Id}}

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{QIBToken}}

{
    "id": {{Id}},
    "value": "{{Value}}"
}'

$Response = Invoke-SimpleRequest -Syntax $Sample -Context $Data
```

Please refer to GitHub for detail introductions

Answer (score 0):

This method downloads the content:

```
# PowerShell 2 version
$WebRequest=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials=$true
#$WebRequest.Credentials=(Get-Credential)
$Data=$WebRequest.DownloadData("http://<url>")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("<full path of file>",$Data)

# PowerShell 5 version
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://<url>" -OutFile "<full path of file>" -UseDefaultCredentials -ContentType
```