# PowerShell Version 2 Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, invoke

I'm needing to run a Powershell script that has the below syntax in it. What would be the PowerShell 2 equivalent of this line be?

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://$Server/api/setobjectproperty.htm?id=$Id&name=Inheritscheduledependency&value=0&username=$User&passhash=$Hash" | out-null
```

This is the full script:

```
param([int]$Id = 5557,[int]$Duration = 1,[string]$Unit = "Hours")

$Server     = "webpage.bla.org"
$User       = "user"
$Hash       = "45093450908"
$DateFormat     = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss";
$StartDate  = (Get-Date).ToString($DateFormat);

switch($Unit){
"Minutes"   { $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($Duration).ToString($DateFormat); }
"Hours"     { $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddHours($Duration).ToString($DateFormat); }
"Days"      { $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($Duration).ToString($DateFormat); }
default     { $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddHours($Duration).ToString($DateFormat); }
}

Invoke-WebRequest "http://$Server/api/setobjectproperty.htm?id=$Id&name=Inheritscheduledependency&value=0&username=$User&passhash=$Hash" | out-null
Invoke-WebRequest "http://$Server/api/setobjectproperty.htm?id=$Id&name=maintenable&value=1&username=$User&passhash=$Hash" | out-null
Invoke-WebRequest "http://$Server/api/setobjectproperty.htm?id=$Id&name=maintstart&value=$StartDate&username=$User&passhash=$Hash" | out-null
Invoke-WebRequest "http://$Server/api/setobjectproperty.htm?id=$Id&name=maintend&value=$EndDate&username=$User&passhash=$Hash" | out-null
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [http requests with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715695/http-requests-with-powershell)

Answer (score 17):

In Powershell 2 you could use the .NET WebClient Class as @KIM Taegyoon points out in an older question about PowerShell and webrequests. See his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20941552/3949759)

In short:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com")
```