# POST string to php script using PowerShell

Tags: php, string, powershell, post, input

I am looking for a method in PowerShell to post a basic string to a php script that looks like this:

```
<?php
$file =  date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".creds";
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

I hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http requests with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715695/http-requests-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to go through the link. It will help you to understand better .It has all the required examples.

[PHP Powershell](http://theboywonder.co.uk/2012/07/29/executing-powershell-using-php-and-iis/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Invoke-WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest) cmdlet in PowerShell 3.0 and above to make a request to your web/PHP service.

The Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet has a bunch of parameters you can use to customise your request, like -Headers (for setting headers), -Body for setting the body content, and -ContentType for setting the content type of your request.

You'll most probably want to use the -Body parameter of the cmdlet to send your simple string.

Follow the link above for details and some examples.