# How to send powershell output to web server

Tags: powershell, apache, webserver

I have a powershell script that generates an output and I can send it by email as an attachment however now I would need to send that output to an apache web server.

I have searched and I didn't found about it and I don't know if is possible to.

If possible, how is that done?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod`: `Invoke-WebRequest $ServerURL -Method Post -Body $dataYouWantToUpload`

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7715759/18667225 ?