# how to pass arguments from asp.net web app to a remote console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, console-application

Can anybody state how can we pass the `data/field/parameter` from a `asp.net web page- code-behind` to a remote console application which calls this page?
Basically, I want this console app to start a timer when it calls that page and stop the timer when it loads.

Also, inside the page itself, it would do the same for `DB` connection. i.e start a timer on `DB connection` and stop it after the query executes. I want this `DB timer` value in the remote console application.

So, how do I pass this `DBtimer` value to the remote console application..??
How would it receive this timer value?

Based on this timer value I have to perform some logic.

Comment: Perhaps start with [WebClient or HttpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988286/what-difference-is-there-between-webclient-and-httpwebrequest-classes-in-net).

Comment: Thanks @Jasen , Your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much