# How to download a string via HTTP from .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I've got a very simple need - my C# code needs to connect to a remote server via HTTP and download a string. A trivial GET request, nothing more.

To ensure that my application remains responsive I also want to impose a timeout (say, 3 seconds) on the operation.

My first thought was to use [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), but that doesn't support any timeouts.

Then I wanted to try the good old [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), but alas - since .NET 4.5 it's [been marked as obsolete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190216.aspx)!

So, what can I use? I checked out the [`System.Net.Http`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.aspx) namespace, but it only allows asynchronous usage, forces to use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx)s, and generally only adds a dozen different layers of abstraction without really adding any new functionality (since it uses the same old [`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) underneath anyway)

I don't want asynchronous stuff, I don't want to involve other threads, I don't want to involve the Tasks framework, I don't want tons of wrappers.

What is the correct way to do this in .NET 4.5?

Comment: It's not the `HttpWebRequest` that is deprecated, it's its constructors. `Do not use the HttpWebRequest constructor. Use the WebRequest.Create method to initialize new HttpWebRequest objects.`

Comment: You could still use WebClient async methods to set a timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/601899/54937

Comment: And you can always shift calls to `WebClient` to a background thread and use a semaphore of some kind (like an `AutoResetEvent`) that does have a timeout.

Comment: @Will - I already wrote that I want to keep it simple and avoid burning another thread needlessly.

Comment: @GSerg - perfect! Please make this into an answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3052637/1386111) is quite good. You can use it just like a `WebClient` and also set the timeout.

Comment: Burning a thread?  Is this 1996?

Comment: If you want to make your application responsive, you *should* use “asynchronous stuff”.

Comment: When Anders Hejlsberg, the guy who's the lead architect on the C# language since 2000, tells you to give `async` and `await` a try, you could at least consider it ;-). [The Future of C# and Visual Basic](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC10/FT09). Come on, do it for Anders...

Comment: @WimOmbelets - Haha, funny! :D But, seriously, I do not see the reason to move processing to another thread if I block the first thread in the meantime.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` class is not deprecated, only its constructors are.

To cite the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx):

> Do not use the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.httpwebrequest.aspx) constructor. Use the [`WebRequest.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx) method to initialize new `HttpWebRequest` objects. If the scheme for the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is `http://` or `https://`, `Create` returns an `HttpWebRequest` object.

Answer (score 2):

Only the constructor is deprecated, not the HttpWebRequest class itself. Use [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx) to create an instance of HttpWebRequest.