# Downloading file from url with timeout

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio 2010 using C# .Net

The program is to save the file from a given url to local drive, with a custom timeout to save time.

Say the url is `http://mywebsite.com/file1.pdf`, and I want to save the file to the directory `C:\downloadFiles\`

Currently, I'm using `WebClient`.

```
WebClient.DownloadFile("http://mywebsite.com/file1.pdf", "C:\downloadFiles\file1.pdf");
```

I am able to save the file, but I ran into some problem.

Sometimes, the url just won't respond, so I have my program try to download 5 times before terminating. I then realize the default timeout for WebClient is too long for my need (like 2 min or something) Is there a simple way to set timeout shorter, say like 15 sec?

I also looked into `HttpWebRequest`, which I can easily set the timeout `HttpWebRequest.Timeout = 15000;`. However, with this method, I have no idea how I can download/save the file.

**So my over all questions is:** Which is more simple, setting timeout for `WebClient`, or saving file using `HttpWebRequest`? And how would I go about doing so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set timeout for webClient.DownloadFile()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own WebClient

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var req = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        req.Timeout = 15000;
        return req;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class if you are using .NET 4.5:

```
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);

    Stream response = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://mywebsite.com/file1.pdf");

    ...
}
```

Here's an example that get's a `json` response in LinqPad: http://share.linqpad.net/aaeeum.linq

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to change timeout with a `WebClient`. But you can use `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()` instead. This will allow you to use `CancelAsync()` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 4 and above you can do something like

```
var wreq = WebRequest.Create("http://mywebsite.com/file1.pdf");
wreq.Timeout = 15000;

var wresp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite("path/to/output/file.pdf"))
{
    wresp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(file); // CopyTo extension only .net 4.0+ 
}
```

Otherwise you could copy it yourself

```
using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite("path/to/output/file.pdf"))
{
    var input = wresp.GetResponseStream();

    var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
    {
        file.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```