# How can I make a WebProxy Timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, proxy, webproxy

I am downloading a string via system.net.WebClient

I am also downloading it using a proxy:

```
 Dim proxy As New Net.WebProxy(grabbedproxy.ToString)
     webClient.Proxy = proxy
```

My basic problem is that I have no idea how to make the downloadstring request timeout after a certain amoun of time.  If the proxy being used is slow it makes my program hang for minutes.  Is there any way to set a timeout time for the proxy so that it will dissconnect itself after a certain amount of seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()` allows you to use CancelAsync() by timer using your own timeout value.

Check also this post, it shows you how to implement a derived class with timeout:

[Set timeout for webClient.DownloadFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile)