# Multiple WebClients finishing very slowly

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, webclient

I have a class that creates multiple `WebClient` classes with different proxies on multiple threads simultaneously.

Unfortunately, some instances of `WebClient` class take quite long to finish. Usually, I end up with ~20 threads that take a few minutes to finish. On the other hand, I spawn hundreds of threads which finish fast.

I tried to create extend the `WebClient` class and set the Timeout property to 20 seconds ([as posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile)), but it didn't change anything.

I'm not showing the whole code, because there would be quite a lot of it (`WebClient` is wrapped in another class). Still, I know the bottle-neck is `WebClient.DownloadString(url)`, because all of the worker threads are processing this specific line whenever I pause debugging during that last step of executing code.

Here's how I use the extended `WebClient`:

```
public string GetHtml(string url)
{
    this.CheckValidity(url);

    var html = "";

    using (var client = new WebDownload())
    {
        client.Proxy = this.Proxy;
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = this.UserAgent;
        client.Timeout = this.Timeout;

        html = client.DownloadString(url);
    }

    return html;
 }
```

**EDIT**

I have just ran a few tests, and some of the threads take up to 7 minutes to finish, all contemplating the `WebClient.DownloadString()` statement.

Furthermore, I have tried setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to `int.MaxValue`, unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried this without threading to get a feel for the expected response time?

Comment: Are they all fetching from the same host by any chance?

Comment: @brumScouse, Yes I have. I believe that the problem might be quality of supplied proxy. It would be great if I could simply set timeout for the whole operation. I suppose I could do this by using `DownloadStringAsync`, waiting for it to finish and throwing an exception after supplied timeout (have just thought of that :D). But is that a good idea?

Comment: @JonSkeet, spot on! They are, but each of the requests uses a different proxy, so that shouldn't be a problem. (I guess?).

Comment: @moskalak: I don't know how the connection pool works in those terms, to be honest. How many different proxies are involved, vs how many requests?

Comment: @JonSkeet: While testing I didn't exceed 200 simultaneous requests, but even when I set max to 40, it ends the same. As for the proxies, there's around 1000 of them, but some are of a bit dubious quality.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thank you all for your help. I think I've found the solution, have checked it and it seems to work pretty well. I would appreciate any comments, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.

I realized that the problem was, I needed simply to cancel `WebClient.DownloadString()` when it reached the specified timeout. Since I haven't found anything that would help me in `WebClient`, I simply called `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync()`. This way, I could use `Task.WaitAll` with timeout to wait for `WebClient` to finish downloading string and then check if the task has finished (to rule out timeout).

Here's the code:

```
public string GetHtml(string url)
{
    var html = "";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // Assign all the important stuff
        client.Proxy = this.Proxy;
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = this.UserAgent;

        // Run DownloadString() as a task.
        var task = client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

        // Wait for the task to finish, or timeout
        Task.WaitAll(new Task<string>[] { task }, this.Timeout);

        // If timeout was reached, cancel task and throw an exception.
        if (task.IsCompleted == false)
        {
            client.CancelAsync();
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }

        // Otherwise, happy. :)
        html = task.Result;
    }
```