# .NET WebClient hanging, but no error

Tags: c#, httprequest, webclient

I have a c#.NET program that is using a WebClient to download a group of files.  It is working fine for most of the files, but one of the files causes the WebClient to hang indefinitely.  The WebClient has a 60 second timeout on it's httpRequest, and it is in a try/catch structure, but still hangs indefinitely without generating an error.

I've tried opening the file in a browser, and the browser also hangs.

What can I do to cause the WebClient to error out in a situation like this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe related to `proxy` setting on your machine.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/601861/197913) should prove helpful.

Comment: I had a similar problem using `HttpWebRequest` and the way I fixed it is to update from .net framework 3.5 to .net 4.0

Comment: Enable System.Net tracing and you will see more info.