# Extending System.Net.WebClient cause editor error in Visual Studio 2013 Unity Tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine

In my unity project, I extended System.Net.WebClient class to add timeout property from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile).

```
class WebDownload : WebClient
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public WebDownload() : this(60000) { }

    public WebDownload(int timeout)
    {
        this.Timeout = timeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

After I save my file, Visual Studio 2013 gives this error :

[image: Error Image]

Even if Visual studio gives that error, program compiled without error and I can use my `WebDownload` object without problem. I tried to do same thing for an empty project and this time it did not give that error.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2013 Unity Tool?

Here is the error stack (in case image is not readable) :

> at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(Object instance,
>   Attribute[] attributes) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSDesignSurface.CreateDesigner(IComponent
>   component, Boolean rootDesigner) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent
>   component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent
>   component, String name) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type
>   componentType, String name) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost
>   host)

Comment: Nothing say that it's a problem with Unity Tool. Based on what we can see on your screenshot, it seems that your "Downloader.cs" file is considered as a generated Windows Form (or something similar). What is inside ?

Comment: @ReMinoer Inside "Downloader.cs" there is only the code I posted in the question. As soon as I copy paste it, the icon of the file is changing from the editor(As I showed with red box in the image). If I delete 'WebClient' extension from the Class definition, it turns into normal.

Comment: Look in your project file if you have something like that : `<Compile Include="Views\Downloader.cs"> <SubType>Form</SubType> </Compile>`. If yes, consider to edit it this way : `<Compile Include="Views\Downloader.cs" />`