# Does WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync() never actually timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, webclient

In the pre-async days, people wanted to know how to set the timeout on `WebClient` and the answer was simply to extend the base class and override `GetWebRequest()` and set the timeout there.

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
{
    // NOTE: this override has no affect if the Async methods are used!!!
    WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Timeout = 20 * 60 * 1000;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).ReadWriteTimeout = 20 * 60 * 1000;
    return request;
}
```

The assumption was that people needed a *longer* timeouts.

Then with the addition of the `xyzTaskAsync()` methods, people wanted to know how to set the timeout, and the answer was to use a CancellationToken driven by a local timer.

So I guess the assumption was that people needed the request to end after a given time.

So **does this mean that** `DownloadFileTaskAsync()` or `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` **never timeout by themselves**? Isn't a timeout failure an inherent part of any network operation?

I've used the `GetWebRequest()` override to set a very small timeout value. It throws the timeout exception when non-async methods are called, but not when the async methods are called.

I've decompiled the System.Net library, but the async methods seem to invoke some cached anonymous lambdas that are not easily discoverable.

Does anyone know with certainty if the `DownloadXyzTaskAsync()` methods execute with the equivalent of an infinite timeout value?

Comment: That override is used by the`TaskAsync` methods. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,2559 http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,1988

Comment: @SLaks Thanks. Forgot about the 'open source' option. Was using a third-party decompiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronous operations are blocking, that means a thread is blocked on some kind of wait handle. That wait can be unlimited (and so infinite if the operation itself doesn't end) or that wait can receive some kind of timeout after which it unblocks and timeouts.

An asynchronous operation, by inherently being asynchronous, doesn't have any active part doing something. There's no thread being blocked or anything similar. That means that it inherently can't really timeout or cancel without something telling it to, and even then the operation is merely abandoned and not cancelled. That something is usually a `CancellationToken` (that may or may not be signaled with a timer after a timeout).

So, this (and any other kind of) asynchronous operation needs something (i.e. a `CancellationToken`) to be able to timeout. It's true that the library can use a timer internally but that is rarely done in .Net as it's unexpected and you can do that yourself with a self cancelling `CancellationToken`.

So, in this specific case and in general, async methods aren't usually affected by a configured timeout. That's also the case with `Socket`, `TcpClient`, `UdpClient`, etc.

Now, if you want confirmation from the actual code of `HttpWebRequest` you can see that the timeout is used to create a timer queue [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,1017). That queue is used to create a timeout timer in [`GetResponse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,2212) but never in [`BeginGetResponse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,613ffcf7266252eb,references). That is the asynchronous option used in the `DownloadXXXAsync` which is used in `DownloadXXXTaskAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the 'open source' option I had forgotten about. (I was using a third party decompiler.) I had seen the reference to the timer queue which is why I was suspicious, but I see clearly now that it is not invoked by the async version of the method.

Comment: It would be a whole new discussion, but as a side comment, I would have thought that a timeout condition was an inherent part of a network protocol in general, and that async invocations would still have to honor it. I guess it makes sense now that it is a client option, not server driven. But it is ubiquitous, isn't it. Browsers and download clients time out all the time.

Comment: @mdisibio as I see it, the .Net guys only give you an API when you can't do the thing yourself (in a reasonable way). Timing out an inner synchronous operation is something you can't do from the outside.