# Error In HTML Export using Enterprise Architect C# api

Tags: bash, enterprise-architect

While doing the Export of the model to HTML, I encountered this error.

"Could not open the file"
"TerInternetGet, File: TerPict1969718.tmp"

At the moment, our team using the C# API to create HTML exports that are later broadly provided to multiple teams in the organization.
The process of creating the export is done via batch script and only one of the models is given this error. As for this particular model, it is possible to create the HTML manually, via the ribbon tools as well as the Automation Interface.
As the file mentioned in the pop-up error changes, we aren´t able to debug this issue, can you be so kind as to explain the processes that are run during the HTML process to pinpoint what is triggering this error? (EA 15.2 - 1555)

```
public void GenerateHtml(string config_path)
        {
            ConfigTemplate configt = new ConfigTemplate();
            configt = config = LoadConfigTemplate(config_path);
 
 
            EA.Collection packages = repository.Models;
 
            //EA.Package child = (EA.Package)packages.GetAt(0);
            EA.Package child = (EA.Package)packages.GetByName(configt.packageName);
 
            EA.Project project;
            project = repository.GetProjectInterface();
            string packageGUID = child.PackageGUID;
            string p = packages.ToString();
            project.RunHTMLReport(packageGUID, configt.exportPath, configt.imageFormat, configt.style, configt.extension);
        }
```

Thank you in advance for any response.

[image]

[image]

EDIT: We tried to execute the bash script with admin cmd and it works just fine. So we suspect it might have anything to do with permissions or configurations. In addition, I updated the post with the code.

Comment: Without the code you are using, we can only guess.

Comment: The code is not the origin of the problem, since when we try to export via EA it works fine. Additionally, we tried to execute the bash script with admin cmd and it works just fine. So we suspect it might have anything to do with permissions or configurations.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is due to something outside of EA. There is one other reference to the same method name: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255880/timeout-not-respected-when-using-downloadfile-overriding-getwebrequest-to-set-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem was caused by a few appendix documents...  We were able to solve the issue by editing and saving without any changes to the files, once we found out the ones that were failing.