# C# - Custom timeout for WebClient

Tags: c#, http, timeout, webclient

I am trying to give custom timeout to `WebClient()` object. I have tried lots of solutions including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile) and lots of others. The conclusion I came up with is setting a custom timeout is not working for `WebClient()` object when you use `DownloadFileAsync()` or `DownloadStringAsync()`. (There are other people saying this too in these posts)

Are there any other solutions that I couldn't see or find on the internet?

Comment: maybe you are doing it wrong include some code

Comment: Why u didn`t want use HttpClient?

Comment: @Valkyriee Nope, I am not doing it wrong. Look at the links I provided. There are replies and comments about setting custom timeout is not working with WebClient.

Comment: @Danny I wanted to use it but it does not support upload/download progress. There is a package which brings this functionality to HttpClient but I don't want to use it. Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: @Zapdos check it, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6849

Comment: Thank you but this code is for downloading. I managed to have a progress bar similar to this solution for downloading, I forgot to mention it. I can provide a code for it. But uploading is a different issue and cannot get a progress report for it.