# In C# how to set timeout while using WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync method?

Tags: c#, async-await, webclient

Now I am using `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` method for http call, I want to migrate the code to async-await model. So, though of using `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` method, but not sure how to set timeout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

Answer (score 4):

The default timeout for `WebClient` is 100 seconds (i believe)

- If you like you can `CancelAsync()` with your own timeout, add pepper and salt to taste.
- You use `HttpWebRequest` rather than `WebClient` (it uses the `HttpWebRequest` internally). Using the `HttpWebRequest` will allow you to set the timeout implicitly.
- You could make a derived class which sets the timeout for the `WebRequest` as seen from this answer

[Set timeout for webClient.DownloadFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601861/set-timeout-for-webclient-downloadfile)

```
public class WebDownload : WebClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Time in milliseconds
    /// </summary>
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public WebDownload() : this(60000) { }

    public WebDownload(int timeout)
    {
        this.Timeout = timeout;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Timeout = this.Timeout;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```